# my browser is skipping home page (Angular) when clicking on the precedent page button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on this angular project and I have this bug:

- I launch the project
- hit localhost:port on browser
- see home page
- clicks on a button
- goes back (precedent page)
- browser exits app (goes back to its google search thingy)

in some other occurrences it doesn't exit the app, it just goes back to the page that is before the page I just came from, it's like the page I was just on isn't being saved into the history of the browser.

here is the routing I'm using:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'accueil/bots', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  {
    path: 'accueil',
    component: HomePageComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'accueil/bots', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'bots', component: MyBotsComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
      { path: 'customers', component: CustomersComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
      { path: 'missions', component: MissionsComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
      { path: 'restitutions', component: ResultTemplatesComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'bot-project/:id',
    component: BotDashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: BotEditorComponent },
      { path: 'state', redirectTo: '' },
      { path: 'state/:stateId', component: BotEditorComponent },
      { path: 'export', component: ExportComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: ConfigureComponent },
      { path: 'deploy', component: DeployBotComponent },
    ],
  },
];


thanks!
```

I think it's some hidden issue in the routing I'm using but I couldn't figure it out quite honestly.

Comment: `redirectTo: 'home/bots'` ? There is no `'home'`  route.

Comment: yeah tried to modify stuff for the post, mb fixed it now